# Как сделать конкретный метод любого класса другом моего класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Основной вопрос в заголовке, идея в ограничении доступа к методу своего класса: `С::serialize()`. (код сильно сокращён)

```
class Type1
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Type& operator&(T t){t.serialize(*this);return *this;}
    template<>Type& operator&(int t){/*полезные действия*/return *this;}
};

class Type2
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Type& operator&(T t){t.serialize(*this);return *this;}
    template<>Type& operator&(int t){/*полезные действия*/return *this;}
};

class C
{
    int v;

    template<typename T> friend T& T::operator&(C);
    template <class T> T& serialize(T&t){t&v; return t;}
public:
    ...
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])// 
{
    Type t;
    C c;
    t & c & c & c;
    return 0;
}
```

Задача - правильно написать `friend`. Вызывать метод `С::serialize` из оператора `Type::operator&()` Классов Type будет неопределённое количество.

```
template<typename T> friend class T;
friend Type& Type::operator&(class C);
friend Type& operator&(class Type,class C);
template<class T>friend T& class T::operator&(C);
template<typename T> friend T& T::operator& < T > (class C);
```

ни один вариант не прокатывает.

Comment: Простите, не вполне понятно: кто к кому должен получить доступ.

Comment: Не очень уверен в возможности вот так, скопом объявить `C` другом для всего, что только предоставляет оператор `&`... Смущает сама постановка задачи - в чем тогда вообще смысл приватности `serialize`? Конкретные типы удовлетворить легко, `friend Type1& Type1::operator&(C);`, но я так понимаю, вас это не устраивает?

Comment: Смысл приватности в том, чтобы `serialize` можно было вызвать только из методов, а не напрямую из класса С. Скрыть от пользователя класса возможность вызова метода `serialize`.  Если ответ не обнаружится придётся применять множественное наследование интерфейсов. :(( `class I1{public:/*внешний интерфейс*/}; class I2{public:serialize();}`  и пользователям предоставлять интерфейс I1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что сделать именно так вообще возможно. Если бы такое было возможно, то компилятору бы пришлось прочёсывать все классы в поисках метода. Но утверждать, что так нельзя не буду — нет доказательств.

Т.к. задача не совсем ясна, то я могу предложить следующее решение:

```
class C
{
    int v = 10;

    template<typename T> friend T& operator&(T&, const C&);
    template <class T> T& serialize(T&t) const { t&v; return t; }
};

template<typename T>
T& operator&(T& t, const C& c)
{
    c.serialize(t); return t;
}

class Type1
{
public:
    Type1& operator&(int t) {/*полезные действия*/return *this; }
};

class Type2
{
public:
    Type2& operator&(int t) {/*полезные действия*/return *this; }
};
```

Как Вы можете видеть, я вынес операторы из Ваших `Type#` классов в один общий, и сделал эту функцию другом `C`. Сложно сказать, насколько это поможет Вам, т.к. повторюсь — Ваша задача не совсем ясна.

Comment: Пост сюда был последней попыткой решить вопрос. Такой вариант рассматривался. Он не подходит, т.к. метод `operator&` в семействе классов `Type` шаблонный со специализацией для встроенных типов уникальной для каждого класса `Type`. А если вынести операторный метод, то не будет возможности сделать различные специализации.

Comment: @Zax, обновите Ваш вопрос с примером, в котором мой код не будет работать, но который Вам необходим.

Comment: @Zax, посмотрел я Ваш код, что по Вашему не будет работать с моим решением? Вы можете использовать `Type1` & `Type2` как c `C`, так и с `int`, при этом будет использована соответствующая реализация. Вам не нужна специализация шаблона, совсем.

Comment: main.cpp(15): warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
1>          main.cpp(38) : see reference to function template instantiation 'T &operator &<Type1>(T,C)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Type1
1>          ]         это если собрать как есть

Comment: и если template<typename T>
T& operator&(T&t, C c) то тоже ошибка. main.cpp(38): error C2593: 'operator &' is ambiguous
1>          main.cpp(13): could be 'T &operator &<Type1>(T &,C)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Type1
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(8): or       'T &operator &<Type1>(T,C)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Type1
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Type1, C)'

Comment: Простите, видимо я что-то недопонял в примере. Компилятор Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2 при любой расстановке ссылок выдаёт ошибки.

Comment: @Zax, поправил ссылки в коде, теперь не должно быть проблем.